# Gaussian fit for dice rolls has peculiar constants, looking for their origin

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

For a programming project I want to describe huge quantities of dice rolls using a gaussian. Hence I set out to find a relation between:

- $size$ = the number of sides a single die has,
- $amount$ = the number of same sided dice rolled at once,

and the gaussian that describes the probability of rolling a specific total sum $x$ with all of these dice. Dice in this case mean some abstract object that on 'rolling' give a random integer number between 1 and $size$ (inclusive), just like normal dice would.

Let the gaussian be: $$ P(x) = A * e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} $$

Where usually $A = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}$ is used as normalisation constant while $\mu = amount * \frac{size + 1}{2}$ is straightforward.

Now, using several parameters for $size$ and $amount$ I fitted simulated distributions to the gaussian using $A$ and $\sigma$ as fitting parameters. I found the following holds true in very good approximation when $size$ and $amount$ are both bigger than like 4:

$$\sigma = a * size * \sqrt{amount}$$
$$A = \frac{b}{size * \sqrt{amount}}$$

with the two constants:

$$a \approx 0.28915937$$
$$b \approx 137445.476$$

Now I am asking myself (and in extension you) if the constants $a$ and $b$ that appear here can somehow be explained. I would be surprised if these are just some *shrug* numbers that randomly appear in a system as simple as same-sided dice and would be much more satisfied if they could be explained and maybe consist of well-known numbers like $\pi$ and $e$. Please help me satisfy my curiosity here!

I am aware that I am using a continuous probability distribution function to describe discrete events but I am pretty sure this does not invalidate the question. Also I did not study mathematics, so please assume that I only have surface knowledge regarding black magic aka mathematics.

edit: I should add that the distribution I fitted is a histogram of $x$ over 100k simulated rolls. Therefore the integral over the whole distribution is not 1 and $b$ is large for this reason. I am mainly interested in the $\sigma$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Math mode isn’t suitable for italicizing text – as you can see, the spacing gets messed up. To include text in formulas, use `\text`. To italicize text, enclose it in single asterisks. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip. Coming from coding I was using the words size and amount as variables and thought therefore math mode would be the logical thing to use. I'll keep this in mind for any next post or edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem). The variance of a [discrete uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) (what you call a die is a special case of a discrete uniform distribution on an interval starting at $1$) is $\frac{n^2-1}{12}$, where $n$ is the length of the interval. By the central limit theorem, if you add a large number $m$ of such independent uniformly generated numbers, the resulting distribution is approximated by a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with variance $m\cdot\frac{n^2-1}{12}$. For large $n$, the $-1$ can be neglected, so the standard deviation is asymptotically $\frac{n\sqrt m}{\sqrt{12}}$. So your ‘peculiar constant’ is $a=\frac1{\sqrt{12}}\approx0.2887$. As to $b$, you seem to have inadvertently shifted it by some powers of $10$; as you rightly point out, it should be determined by $A=\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and thus $b=\frac1{a\sqrt{2\pi}}=\sqrt{\frac6\pi}\approx1.382$.

Comment: Perfect! \frac{1}{\sqrt{12}}... never could have guessed this. This explains a and b. The power of 10 was a missing information which I added later in the bottom edit. Thanks a lot!